# Is this the right equation format for a logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

I was reading a paper and the authors wrote the equation for a logistic regression like this: Pr(yf = 1|X,C) = P(β1Xf + β2Cf + σs + ρr +  f sr > 0)

Is this a typical way of writing a logit regression?

Comment: I usually see $y=\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x)/(1+\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x))$

Comment: please (a) clarify the notation you are using, (b) write down the equation using markdown

Answer (score 1):

In general, the equation for the logistic regression model is giving you the probability (Pr) of the binary outcome being 1 (yf = 1) given some information about predictor variables (explanatory variables; e.g., X and C).

Example: What is the probability (Pr) of suffering a stroke (Pr y = 1) given some well-known predictors like x1 = diabetes, x2 = hypertonia etc.

There are two forms of the equations (both are the same just written in an other way): see picture below

[image]